# Remove lines from a text file(that are not aligned) and saving it in another one in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of text files that are aligned(fixed width), but sometimes in the middle of the text file there's a line or two that's not properly aligned:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5
word1longerword2 word3 word4 word5
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5
word1 word2longerthanusualword3 word4 word5
```

How can I remove those lines and save it in another textfile?
If I have multiple text files in the directory, can I recursively run through all of them and just create one new text file?
How can I make the new file comma delimited?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What version of Powershell are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Select-String`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) cmdlet:

```
Select-String '\S{10,}' -NotMatch .\data\foo.txt | select -Expand Line
```

The pattern `\S{10,}` matches sequences of at least 10 consecutive non-whitespace characters. The parameter `-NotMatch` inverts the selection, so that only lines not matching the pattern are selected.

Comment: What if my strings have different widths? Say word1 can be anything from 0-10 and word2 can be 20-25 characters long. \S{10,25}?

Comment: @user3439076 If the different columns have different maximum widths you could use a positive match for all columns: `Select-String '^\S{0,10} \S{20,25} \S{5,17} \S{0,15} \S{1,20}$' | ...`.